# How to prove non-equality of terms produced by two different constructors of the same inductive in coq?

Tags: coq

Consider I have an inductive:

```
Inductive DirectSum{L R: Type}: Type := 
| Left: L -> DirectSum L R
| Right: R -> DirectSum L R
.
```

How do I prove that

```
forall L R: Type, forall l: L, forall r: R, Left L <> Right R.
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `easy` tactic is powerful enough to solve this:

```
Inductive DirectSum (L R: Type): Type :=
| Left: L -> DirectSum L R
| Right: R -> DirectSum L R
.
Arguments Left {_ _}.
Arguments Right {_ _}.

Goal forall L R: Type, forall l: L, forall r: R, Left l <> Right r.
easy.
Qed.
```

The reason this works, internally, is pattern matching. We can write a function that returns `True` on `Left` and `False` on `Right`. If the terms were equal, we would get `True = False`, which entails a contradiction.